# Hide input fields by default and show it when selecting a value from select field

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my code, I have one select field and two read only fields. I need to hide the read only fields by default (while loading the page) and need to show these fields if any of the value selected from the select field. The values to select field is getting from mysql data base using php.

```
<select id ="name" name="name" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Wallet</option>

    <?php
    //my query       
    echo '<option value="' . $row['group'] . '">' . $row['group'] . '</option>';

    ?>

</select>

<input id ="od" value="<?php echo $od ?>" class="form-control" readonly/>
<input id="bal" value="<?php echo $bal ?>" class="form-control" readonly/>
```

Comment: And where is your tries? Did you forget the js code?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to be shown when the option is selected. How would you like to select the elements to be shown / hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
function onNameChange() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  document.getElementById('od').style.display = name.value ? 'inline-block' : 'none'
  document.getElementById('bal').style.display = name.value ? 'inline-block' : 'none'
}
```

```html
<!-- use a change event handler for the select -->
<select id="name" name="name" class="form-control" onchange="onNameChange()" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Wallet</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<!-- Hide the inputs using `display: none` -->

<input id="od" value="<?php echo $od ?>" class="form-control" style="display: none" readonly/>
<input id="bal" value="<?php echo $bal ?>" class="form-control" style="display: none" readonly/>
```